# Unable to change JLabel value

Tags: java, spring, swing, awt

I'm new to NetBeans. I am unable to run this in eclipse. When I try to run this I get an error like `non static variable cannot be referenced from static context`. Please help me to solve.

[image]

```
InetAddress ip;

try {
    ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    String t1= ip.getHostName();

    sysname.setText(t1);               // HERE IS THE ERROR
    //sysname.setText("hi");           // EVEN THIS ALSO MAKE ERROR
} catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(mainframe.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex); 
}
```

Comment: What is `sysname`? Where is it declared?

Comment: sysname means oject of JLabel.

Comment: also add the surrounding function. is it a main? probably something static, that would explain the error

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/), not a picture of part of you code. Also, study [Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) before using the GUI editor.

Answer (score 0):

From the exception you've posted, it seems the code you've shown us is in a `static` method, maybe `main()`, while the variable `sysname` is an instance variable, possibly declared as

```
private JLabel sysname;
```

You cannot access an instance field without an instance, ie from a `static` context.

Answer (score 0):

if it is inside your main, as suggested, use it like this instead:

```
public class test {
JLabel sysname;

private void setAdress() {
    InetAddress ip;

    try {
        ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        String t1 = ip.getHostName();

        sysname.setText(t1); // HERE IS THE ERROR
        // sysname.setText("hi"); // EVEN THIS ALSO MAKE ERROR
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(mainframe.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

and then in your main:

```
Test test = new Test();
test.setAdress();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your problem description, the problem is that you're referencing a non-static instance `sysname` from inside `main`.

To reference `sysname`, you need to have an instance which you don't seem to instantiate.

In nutshell, you can do as follows if your code snippet is from `main` method.

```
public class App {
    private JLabel sysname = new JLabel();

    public static void main() {

            App app = new App();
             app.setIpLabel();

    }

      void setIpLabel() {
     InetAddress ip;

        try {
            ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            String t1 = ip.getHostName();

            sysname.setText(t1); // HERE IS THE ERROR
            // sysname.setText("hi"); // EVEN THIS ALSO MAKE ERROR
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(mainframe.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
}

}
```