# i cant able to modify the value in label while using net beans

Tags: java, swing, api, user-interface

i'm new to Net Beans. When I try to run this I get an error like non static variable cannot be referenced from static context. Please help me to solve. but when i declare the Label inside the main, i can able to get output (in eclipse). net beans didn't allow to change variable declaration.

```
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class Test extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Test() {
        initComponents();
    } // 

    private void initComponents() {
        l1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        name = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        l1.setText("System Name:");
        name.setText("jLabel2");
        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(l1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 172, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(name, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 201, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 21, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(109, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(l1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(name, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(102, 102, 102))
                );
        pack();
    }// 

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(test.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(test.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(test.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(test.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
// 
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Test().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        try {
            ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            name.setText(ip.getHostName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    InetAddress ip;
// Variables declaration - do not modify 
    private javax.swing.JLabel l1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel name;
// End of variables declaration 
}
```

Comment: *"i don't know how to align code here"*  To use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.  Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to change JLabel value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18599081/unable-to-change-jlabel-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically telling that you are trying to reference some non-static variable from within a `static context.

Look at you `main` method.  It's decalared as `static`, it does not depend on a given instance of a class to be called.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /*...*/
    try {
        ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        name.setText(ip.getHostName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

InetAddress ip;
// Variables declaration - do not modify 
private javax.swing.JLabel l1;
private javax.swing.JLabel name;
```

But the variables you are trying to access are not (`static`), they relay on a particular instance of the class that they are declared in (AKA instance variables).

As it stands, the only choice you have is to move the offending piece of code into the constructor of the class or some other non-static method that you can call...

```
public Test() {
    initComponents();
    try {
        ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        name.setText(ip.getHostName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
} //
```

Take the time to have a read through [Understanding Instance and Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

You may also want to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Comment: thank you very much. it really working. and i have one more doubt. 
what is the minimum percentage of free space required to show color of drive to blue?
i mean, in what percent of disk usage change the color of drive to red?

Comment: That is entirely up to you to decide

Comment: want to know answer for this question.
http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130904040735AAvRzRZ

Answer (score 0):

This error is not related to netbeans. Rather you are getting this as your are referencing the non static variables from static method.

So for short fix you can make your variables static. For long fix do not refer them from main method rather create separate method with the code that you have in main and call that method from main like new ClassName().methodName(); in this case there will be no need to declare variables static.